# Spring Boot Jsoup Get values from website (load values through javascript (Dynamic Loading)) - Sometimes 500 error , Sometimes 200 Ok

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsoup

I created a spring boot web API to get earthquake values from the website.

I have a problem in `getEarthQuakeDataFromAfad` method. After sending a request to `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/earthquakes/afad` , I got sometimes two results (500 and 200) shown below . It could be due to network latency or other factors but I couldn't solve it.

**500 Internal Error**

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-06-13T21:35:37.408+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/api/v1/earthquakes/afad"
}

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:100) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:106) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:302) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:385) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:504) ~[na:na]
    at com.deprem.depremapi.utils.EarthQuakeDataParser.getEarthQuakeDataFromAfad(EarthQuakeDataParser.java:93) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.deprem.depremapi.service.EarthQuakeService.getEarthQuakeDataFromAfad(EarthQuakeService.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.deprem.depremapi.api.EarthquakeController.getAllEarthquakesForAfad(EarthquakeController.java:39)
```

**200 OK**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "date": "2023-06-14 00:10:03",
        "timestamp": -1231544328,
        "latitude": 38.421,
        "longitude": 36.639,
        "depth": 7.0,
        "size": {
            "md": 0.0,
            "ml": 2.8,
            "mw": 0.0
        },
        "location": "Localtion Value",
        "afadId": "590282",
        "attribute": "ML"
    },
    ...

}
```

Here is the method shown below

```
public List<EarthquakeAfad> getEarthQuakeDataFromAfad() throws IOException, ParseException {

        log.info("EarthQuakeDataParser | getEarthQuakeDataFromAfad is working");

        List<EarthquakeAfad> earthquakeList = new ArrayList<>();

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(Constants.AFAD_LINK).get();

        Elements trs = doc.select("tr");

        trs.remove(0);

        log.info("EarthQuakeDataParser | getEarthQuakeDataFromAfad | trs size : " + trs.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < trs.size(); i++) {

            Element tr = trs.get(i);
            Elements tds = tr.select("td");

            String earthquakeType = tds.get(4).text();

            EarthquakeAfad earthquake = EarthquakeAfad.builder()
                    .id((i+1))
                    .date(tds.get(0).text())
                    .timestamp((int) LocalDateTime.parse(tds.get(0).text(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
                            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli())
                    .latitude(Double.parseDouble(tds.get(1).text()))
                    .longitude(Double.parseDouble(tds.get(2).text()))
                    .depth(Double.parseDouble(tds.get(3).text()))
                    .size(Size.builder()
                            .md(earthquakeType.equals("MD") ? Double.parseDouble(tds.get(5).text()) : 0)
                            .ml(earthquakeType.equals("ML") ? Double.parseDouble(tds.get(5).text()) : 0)
                            .mw(earthquakeType.equals("MW") ? Double.parseDouble(tds.get(5).text()) : 0)
                            .build())
                    .location(tds.get(6).text())
                    .afadId(tds.get(7).text())
                    .attribute(earthquakeType)
                    .build();

            earthquakeList.add(earthquake);
        }

        return earthquakeList;
    }
```

How can I fix the issue?

**Editted**

I also use httputil but it still got the same error.

Here is the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.57.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the code shown below

```
// Create a WebClient instance (headless browser)
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

// Enable JavaScript execution
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

// Disable CSS to improve performance (optional)
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);

// Load the AFAD link in HtmlUnit
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(Constants.AFAD_LINK);

// Wait for the page to finish loading JavaScript and rendering
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000);

// Get the updated HTML content from HtmlUnit
String html = page.asXml();

// Close the WebClient to free up resources
webClient.close();

// Parse the HTML using Jsoup
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements trs = doc.select("tr");
```

Here is the link : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/DepremApi)

Answer (score 0):

Well the exception clearly states the reason of 500: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in `EarthQuakeDataParser.getEarthQuakeDataFromAfad`, line 93.

According to code above that line, your `Jsoup.connect(Constants.AFAD_LINK).get()` fetches a response with no `tr` html tag in it.

If requested page uses javascript to load data dynamically, you might need [HTML Unit](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io) library to get page as it looks in a browser. [Here](https://riptutorial.com/jsoup/example/16274/parsing-javascript-generated-page-with-jsoup-and-htmunit) is a brief example.

Comment: If I experience inconsistent results where sometimes you get all values from `doc.select("tr")`, while other times you get 0 values, it could be due to dynamic loading of the table data using JavaScript. In such cases, you can try executing the JavaScript code on the page to ensure that the necessary data is loaded before parsing the HTML. This is my issue. Can you revise your answer if possible?

Comment: I also used it but nothing changed I still got the same issue.